# how to check whether a particular items is selected from combo-box in java (determining with the number of element selected)

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jcombobox

I added a combo box to my JFrame and those items are added from an array. What i want to know is that how to check whether and items is selected so that i can do some function with that like;

```
String[] osCM = {"--Select--", "Windows", "Mac", "Unix", "Linux" };     
JComboBox cmbOS = new JComboBox(osCM);
cmbOS.setBounds(116, 69, 149, 20);
add(cmbOS); 

if(//code to check a particular item is selected){
    //do some function
}else if(//code to check a particular item is selected){
    //do some function
}else{
    //do some function
}
```

Please help. Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if(cmbOS.getSelectedIndex() == 0)